# My pl sql block is executing for only 15 min i need to increase the execution time in toad

Tags: sql, toad, plsql-package

I need to increase PL/SQL Block execution time more than 15 min in toad.
 Is there any settings in toad means suggest me ?

Comment: What do you mean? a) your query/procedure/whatever works for 15 minutes but doesn't produce the result and terminates for some reason so you'd want to let it work some time longer, b) your query/procedure/whatever works for 2 minutes but for some reason you'd want to make it work more than 15 minutes so that you'd be able to do some testing, c) something else?

Answer (score 0):

The PL/SQL block is execution is not controlled by TOAD. TOAD is a client tool, the execution of the PL/SQL block takes place in the server side.

You might want to check the contents of the PL/SQL block to see what is going on. You can post a simple, verifiable test case in this post itself so people can take a look and suggest alternatives if its not optimized